# Solving CodingBat sum28 and withoutTen with array lists

Tags: java

So I just finished some problems off of codingbat.com, sum 28 and withoutTen, and I wanted to know if there was a way to do them with array lists rather than just arrays. I am trying to get some practice with array lists before my next coding assignment.

Comment: you can use an ArrayList the same way you use an array; look at the documentation.

Comment: Start with reading SO FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if your question is "can I use array lists instead of the arrays on codingbat?", the answer is yes.

Just a couple of small points change.

With arrays, you'd use `array.length` to get the size. For arraylists, it is `arraylist.size()`

To access elements in an array, you use `array[0]`. For an arraylist, it is `arrayList.get(0)`.

Finally, it initialize an array, you use `int[] array = new int[10];`. For an arraylist, you'd use `ArrayList<Intenger> name = new ArrayList<Integer>();`. You typically won't assign it a size. To add elements to it, use `name.add(5)`.

Just make sure to add `import java.util.ArrayList;` at the top of your class so that you can actually access all of these methods.

I hope that helps. Good luck :)